# How can I return only the bold words in the body of a RichTextBox in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, return, cpu-word, bold

```
private void SubmitButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
           
            myWeb.Source = new Uri ("https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=" + titleWord.Text + " " + boldWord.Text);

        }
```

I got a button that searches google images. There is a textbox input for a Title (named titleWord) and a RichTextBox input (with the Run named boldWord). I only want the bold words in the RichTextBox to be searched, not the whole text.

```
<RichTextBox Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="150" Margin="10,4,0,0" Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="220">
            <FlowDocument>
                <Paragraph>
                    <Run Name="boldWord" />
                </Paragraph>
            </FlowDocument>
        </RichTextBox>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer here is [Find Bold Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21306420/how-i-can-read-contents-from-richtextbox-with-information-is-it-bolded-underlin) And I put another method. You should scroll through a set of `InlineCollection` inside the paragraphs and find texts that have the features you want.

**xaml code for test**

```
<RichTextBox x:Name="rchTextbox" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="150" Margin="10,4,0,0" Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="220">
   <FlowDocument>
       <Paragraph>
           <Run Text="Normal Text 1" />
           <Run Text="Bold Test 1" FontWeight="Bold"></Run>
           <Run Text=" Normal Text 2" FontWeight="Normal"></Run>
           <Run Text="Bold Text 2" FontWeight="Bold"></Run>
        </Paragraph>
   </FlowDocument>
</RichTextBox>
```

**and .cs code**

```
List<string> boldTexts = new List<string>();
foreach (Paragraph p in rchTextbox.Document.Blocks)
{
    foreach (var inline in p.Inlines)
    {
       if (inline.FontWeight == FontWeights.Bold)
       {
           var textRange = new TextRange(inline.ContentStart, inline.ContentEnd);
           boldTexts.Add(textRange.Text);
           MessageBox.Show(textRange.Text);
       }
    }
}
```